# IBM Cloud Dev Ops Memory Discrepency between CF App command and SSH top command

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I am having an issue with my deployed Flask app on IBM Cloud where each API call is resulting in an incremental level of memory used according to the cf app  command.

Since I cannot share my code my question here is related to my debugging checks. Specifically I'm wondering why the SSH top (or free) command says I have 32gb of total memory (KiB Mem row) but the cf app command says that I have 7 instances with 2gb each (the configuration I chose).

Am I interpreting one of these incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're comparing two different attributes. CF Max allocated memory with max available memory within a CF container. You allocated 2GB per Instance for your app, with 7 instances total. But that doesn't mean *they use 2GB memory*.

You can view actual memory usage in the IBM Cloud details of an app. Click on the app then click `Runtime` on the left.

Here is an example screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. cf apps command gives me both the max and the used (what your "actual" is pointing to). The confusion though is why the top command in the shell tells me that I have around 32gb of total memory when the cf apps command properly tells me the memory used (as well as the max). Im really more concerned with why the ssh top command reports such a large amount of memory available because its tough figuring out if the cd apps command is telling me all used or if it includes cached/buffer.